# changing virtualenv folder on windows

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenv-commands

after a computer fix my python projects dir (windows) changed (say from d: to f:).
now all my virtualenvs are broken. after activating the env the project inside the virtualenv can't find the dependencies and the custom scripts (from the env\scripts folder)won't work

tried running:

```
virtualenv --relocateble ENV_NAME (with the env name ..)
```

like in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153113/virtualenv-relocatable-does-it-really-work) and it outputted a lot of lines like:

```
Script agent\Scripts\deactivate.bat cannot be made relative
```

and my virtualenv is still broken.

when I manually changed activate.bat `set VIRTUAL_ENV` to the new path. some scripts work again. but the relocate scripts still doesn't run and most of the scripts are still broken

even running the python interpeter fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python27\learn\agent\agent\lib\site.py", line 677, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\Python27\learn\agent\agent\lib\site.py", line 666, in main
    aliasmbcs()
  File "F:\Python27\learn\agent\agent\lib\site.py", line 506, in aliasmbcs
    import locale, codecs
  File "F:\Python27\learn\agent\agent\lib\locale.py", line 19, in <module>
    import functools
ImportError: No module named functools
```

is there any way to fix this? HELP

**Update:** I also changed manually the shebang python interpeter line in all scripts in ENV\Scripts. now all fail with the same python failure as above

**Another Update:** to @udi the system python path is:

```
['', 'C:\\dev\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.6.37-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\
dev\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\dev\\Python27\\lib
\\site-packages\\numpy-1.7.1-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\dev\\Python27\\lib\\site-pac
kages\\pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\dev\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\p
ytz-2013b-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\dev\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\python_dateutil-2.
1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\dev\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\
\dev\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tornado-3.0.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\dev\\Python27
\\lib\\site-packages\\pyzmq-13.1.0-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\\dev\\Python27\\lib\\si
te-packages\\pygments-1.6-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:
\\dev\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\dev\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\dev\\Python27\\lib\\plat-
win', 'C:\\dev\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\dev\\Python27', 'C:\\dev\\Python27\
\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\dev\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-
py2.7.egg-info']
```

since I can't run python from the virtualenv, I can't print the python path from there

Comment: Did you change your python version or platform?

Comment: Can you add the printout of `python` > `import sys` > `sys.path`?

Comment: yes, the new system has a newer version of python (I think, not sure).adding the system python sys.path into the question

Comment: is this the `sys.path` under your virtualenv?

Comment: @Udi no, I can't get the sys path straight from python in the virtualenv since I can't get the python interpreter to run fron the env. But I'll post PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your system and local environments create a mix of libraries and binaries from different versions of python.

Chances are you would need to delete `Lib`, `Scripts` and `Include` and start again with  `virtualenv .`.  You might be able to save the `site-packages` folder, but if you have `requirements.txt` files, you should probably reinstall packages instead (see also: [How do I install from a local cache with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806448/how-do-i-install-from-a-local-cache-with-pip) ).

Anyway, I believe you can create a script that does all this in one step.

Comment: hmm. I know I can reinstall a virtualenv, and I do have a requirement.txt from a pip freeze.  but I'm not happy with this solution. if nothing else pops up, I'll just recheckout the repo, and reinstall it

Comment: You can try copying `Lib` and exe files in `Scripts` from a fresh virtualenv, but it's the same :-)

Comment: I suspect copying would make it worse, currently I'm trying your suggestion of a fresh virtualenv with a reinstall of packages, hold your fingers for me.

Answer (score 22):

Correcting python directory path in `ENV_FOLDER\Lib\orig-prefix.txt` helped me

Comment: This was my issue when moving from computer to computer

Comment: Worked for me too. I had reinstalled Python (Anaconda) into different directory.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I installed both py2 and py3 on my windows 10. And got this error by create virtualenv by using `virtualenv xxx` directly. After purging folder xxx and reinstalling with `virtualenv -p TARGET_PY_EXE xxx` everything works smoothly.
Hope this will help multiple python windows users.
By the way, I simply create env variables as PY2 and PY3 instead of adding absolute paths into `PATH`.