# How to rebuild virtualenvs after deleting associated python interpreter

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have a number of django projects organized with the following directory structure using win7 (I'm using GIT_BASH/mingw for my command line) :

```
envs--r1--project1
        --project2
        --Include
        --Library
        --Scripts--python.exe
python275--
```

The idea being here that the different projects have a common environment and I can activate that environment from each projects root directory using:

```
$ source ../Scripts/activate
```

I don't understand exactly how it happened but it turned out that the interpreter ( listed above as python.exe ) was linked somehow to a second python folder above.

I deleted the python275 folder ( AAHH!!) , not realizing its importance, resulting in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site.py", line 703, in   main() File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site.py", line 692, in main aliasmbcs() File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site.py", line 515, in aliasmbcs import locale, codecs File "C:\envs\r1\lib\locale.py", line 19, in   import functools ImportError: No module named functools
```

I have reinstalled the correct python folder but the error persists. Can anyone advise me on how to rebuild the virtualenvs so I can go back to the way it was?

edit:

```
(r1)
/C/envs/r1/Scripts
$ import reload(functools)
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
(r1)
/C/envs/r1/Scripts
$ python.exe import reload(functools)
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
(r1)
/C/envs/r1/Scripts
$ python.exe reload functools        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site.py", line 703, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site.py", line 692, in main
    aliasmbcs()
  File "C:\envs\r1\lib\site.py", line 515, in aliasmbcs
    import locale, codecs
  File "C:\envs\r1\lib\locale.py", line 19, in <module>
    import functools
ImportError: No module named functools


(r1)
/C/envs/r1/Scripts
$ reload(functools)
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
(r1)
/C/envs/r1/Scripts
$ python.exe reload(functools)
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
(r1)


/C/envs/r1/Scripts
$ python.exe  test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\envs\r1\lib\site.py", line 703, in <module>
    main()
  File "f:\envs\r1\lib\site.py", line 692, in main
    aliasmbcs()
  File "f:\envs\r1\lib\site.py", line 515, in aliasmbcs
    import locale, codecs
  File "f:\envs\r1\lib\locale.py", line 19, in <module>
    import functools
ImportError: No module named functools
```

Comment: i think you need reload functools where that `import functools` is ! and change it to `import reload(functools)`

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to python. would you mind explaining further? What and where is functools ?

Comment: as in your `Traceback ` error says you have this import error `ImportError: No module named functools` so in python if you change a module or delete and built it again  you need to reload module so i suggest reload `functools` i think its in this path `ImportError: No module named functools`

Comment: add `reload(functools)` above of `import functools` than give me the result !

Comment: OK , please see above.

Comment: where you add that you must add it in a `.py` file  !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying correctly. I've created a new file called test.py and tried both: "reload(functools.py)" and "reload(functools)" in it. the I ran it. Please see above:

Comment: As we can see from the stacktrace, the error occurs before test.py is executed.
could you check if the lib directory has the file `functools.py` it is one of the python modules that is imported by the interpreter before executing any file?

Comment: there is no functools.py in C:\envs\r1\Lib

Comment: this advice to reload functools, in python code, makes no sense to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest reinstalling Python and virtualenv from scratch in your case, and then re-creating the environment(s).

- Make sure you have a working Python 2.7.5 installation on your system.
- Make sure you have `pip` installed ([see docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html)).
- Make sure `pip` is linked to the Python installation above (check the output of `pip -V`, it should contain the correct system-wide Python path).
- Do a clean install of virtualenv using `pip install virtualenv`.
- Create and activate the environment for your projects.
- Reinstall within your new environment all the modules you had installed in your old environment.

  This may be a tricky one.

  - If you have an up-to-date file such as `requirements.txt`
    with all the packages required, then
    you're all set (`pip install -r requirements.txt` should do it).
  - If you don't have requirements listed, or they aren't up-to-date, then
    check manually which packages you had installed in your old environment.
    For that you should locate `site-packages` directory within your old virtualenv
    (should be under `Library` probably) and look what's in there.
    Every non-system package you recognize in `site-packages` directory
    you install into your new environment (normally using `pip install` but
    some packages may have custom instructions).

That's what I did when it happened to me. I wasn't able to simply rebuild the environment, so I did the reinstall for cleanness.

Comment: Thank you , I used a variant of your answer to fix my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv). You can associate the virtualenv to a python version.

You indicate the Python interpreter to use with the flag -p or --python (e.g --python=python2.5)

```
    virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.6 <path/to/new/virtualenv/>
```

But this is just works for creating new environments. You would need to access your old virtualenv and execute:

```
     pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

The file requirements.txt would contain all the apps you installed in the old virtual environment and their respective versions. Now, from the new environment you have created, run:

```
     pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You should active the virtual environment.

```
     $ source /yourvirtualenvpath/bin/activate

     $ pip freeze > /home/user/requirements.txt

     $ deactivate 

     $ source /yourNEWvirtualenvpath/bin/activate

     $ pip install -r /home/user/requirements.txt
```

Comment: Emily , thanks for looking at this. What directory should I execute the pip freeze from?

Comment: Thanks Emily, when I do the pip freeze I get "ImportError: No module named functools" just like above.

Comment: At this point I'm beginning to suspect that I corrupted something when I deleted the python275 folder. If someone could show me how to rebuild from scratch using newly installed python275 folder as the interpreter I would accept this as an answer. - Bill

Comment: Sorry I couldn't answer before, check this post, seems like the same problem you're having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786287/changing-virtualenv-folder-on-windows

Comment: Thanks for your hard work on this. it didn't hrlp me but I'm awarding the bounty to you