# Python Virtualenv directory change

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I switch between my laptop and desktop, and decided to change the drive letter of my project under virtualenv. I switched the activate.bat of set `"VIRTUAL_ENV=D:\djangoheroku\env"` to `X:\djangoheroku\env\` Now when I try to pip it gives me this error:

> `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"d:\djangoheroku\env\scripts\python.exe"  "X:\djangoheroku\env\Scripts\pip.exe" --version'`

I'm not sure where to change this path. What file is this in?

Switched it back to D:\ to re-create virtual env, but now getting error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named runpy

Comment: Best not try that. Virtual environment is horribly touchy about location. Make sure you use `--relocatable` option just before moving. See [virtualenv relocatable — does it really work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153113/virtualenv-relocatable-does-it-really-work) and the dupe it links to. In general, recreating an environment from `requirements.txt` or `pip freeze` might be a better alternative.

Comment: @Amadan Ah that sucks. I'll go ahead and recreate a new env then. Thanks!